# How is asynchronous event delivery triggered in eclipse OSGi?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I am sending and posting `Events` in eclipse OSGi using the `EventAdmin`. Sending works fine, but I can't receive posted `Events`. What is the mechanism that delivers posted `Events`? Can I trigger this mechanism manually?

Comment: You have 'eclipse-plugin' in your tags - if this is just for plugins `IEventBroker` provides an easier to use interface to the event system.

Comment: Disabling 'Run in UI thread' in the Run Configuration fixed the problem, can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Receiving events uses the [whiteboard pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiteboard_Pattern). You publish an OSGi service with interface org.osgi.service.event.EvenHandler. You use service property EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC to define which topics you listen too.

```
@Component(
    property = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC + "=my/topic"
)
public class MyReceiver implements EventHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println("Event received");
    }

}
```

For all details see the [EventAdmin service spec](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.event.html). There is also a nice [tutorial at Vogella](http://blog.vogella.com/2017/05/16/osgi-event-admin-publish-subscribe/).